# Explode integer range with minuses

Tags: php

Is any better solution for get first and second value exploded by "-" with negative values than use explode function and check how many minuses are there?

```
$list = [
    '10-20',
    '12-14',
    '-5-10',
    '-10--2'
];
```

I would like to receive:

```
$first = 10; $second = 20;
$first = 12; $second = 14;
$first = -5; $second = 10;
$first = -10; $second = -2;
```

Comment: Don't use the minus sign as a separator.

Comment: Unfortunately this is external API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to explode your string, searching for a `-` which is preceded by a digit:

```
foreach ($list as $item) {
    list($first, $second) = preg_split('/(?<=\d)-/', $item);
    echo "\$first = $first, \$second = $second\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$first = 10, $second = 20 
$first = 12, $second = 14 
$first = -5, $second = 10 
$first = -10, $second = -2
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/3Cod3)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Can you explain regexp "<="?

Comment: @jesidebun the `(?<=\d)` structure is a positive lookbehind (`<` makes it a lookbehind, `?=` makes it positive) for a digit (`\d`). So the `-` (the pattern we are splitting on) will only match if it is preceded by a digit.